# Maximum principle of the gradient of harmonic extension under weak regularity assumption

Tags: elliptic-pde

I have a question which is very likely to be trivial, but I'm stuck on it! Suppose $f \in W^{1, 2}(B_2(0))$ and $\|{\nabla f\|}_{L^{\infty}(B_2(0)\setminus B_1(0))} < \infty$. Consider then the harmonic extension of $f$
$$ 
\begin{cases}
 \Delta g = 0 &\text{in }B_1(0),\\
 g = f &\text{on }\partial B_1(0).
\end{cases}
$$
Does a maximum principle for $\nabla g$ hold in such a setting? I.e. something of the form $\|\nabla g\|_{L^{\infty}(B_1(0))} \le \|{\nabla f\|}_{L^{\infty}(B_2(0)\setminus B_1(0))}$?

Or at least an inequality like $\|\nabla g\|_{L^{\infty}(B_1(0))} \le C \|{\nabla f\|}_{L^{\infty}(B_2(0)\setminus B_1(0))}$, for some constant $C>0$ independent of $f$?

Thanks!

Comment: It certainly does not hold in 1 dimension